# Can I tell solely from an IP address if a request came from a mobile phone network?

Tags: mobile, tcp, ip

Assuming I can't rely on there being a user agent string, can I tell simply from the IP address if a connected client originates on a mobile network?

Comment: Network or client? What about mobile clients on WiFi?

Comment: Network, and assuming mobile clients on WiFi are not relevant, or can be counted as not being on a mobile network.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

there are certain IP ranges that are dedicated to mobile networks by their owners (i just googled the [adresses for RIM](http://btsc.webapps.blackberry.com/btsc/viewdocument.do?noCount=true&externalId=KB11036&sliceId=2&dialogID=63832630&cmd=displayKC&docType=kc&stateId=1%200%2063826436&ViewedDocsListHelper=com.kanisa.apps.common.BaseViewedDocsListHelperImpl) (blackberry)  ). There is no IP range dedicated to mobile networks by the IANA, though, so you would have to go search the ranges for every possible provider. Further, you would have to search for the addresses of every mobile to web proxy (i.e. the one used by opera mobile). And you would still NOT catch the clients that are on WiFi, use a private proxy or a VPN...

so, in short, yes, you can to a degree tell from an IP address if a client is on a mobile network, but it would require a hard to maintain lookup DB and you wouldn't catch all mobile clients

Answer (score 2):

No not really, these adresses are determined by the provider and his ip-pool. If that ISP provides internet via cable then it's up to that provider to divide his ranges over mobile and cabled. You cannot know for sure which ip goes where for that provider.